# Joomla - Populating JModelList (adding objects to items)

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla2.5

This is my class that extends JModelList:

```
class AkceHnedModelActions extends JModelList
{
   public function getItems()
   {
      $url = '...';

      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
      ));

      // aby me https fungovalo na localhostu, na serveru potom odstranit
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

      // Send the request
      $getResponse = curl_exec($ch);
      $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      if($getResponse == FALSE){
         die(curl_error($ch));
      }
      else
      {
         $results = array();
         $jsonObject = json_decode($getResponse, true);
         foreach ($jsonObject AS $key => $value) {
            $obj = new Action($value);
            $results[] = $obj;
         }
         $this->items = $results;
      }
      return $this;
   }
}
class Action
{
   function __construct(array $data) {
      foreach($data as $key => $val) {
         $this->{$key} = $val;
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to have for each object own row in table in View. I have this code for view:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item): ?>
         <tr class="row"><td><?php echo $item->id ?></td>
         <td><?php print_r($item) ?></td>
         </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't get it to work. I have all array in one row. How can I create list which I can assign to items?

Comment: Try putting your `__construct` function above the `getItems` function and in the same class. It shouldn't have it's own class

Comment: What's the reason your AkceHnedModelActions::getItems() method returns the whole object where it's supposed to return only a list of items? Shouldn't it return $this->items instead of $this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method:

```
(array) AkceHnedModelActions::getItems()
```

returns the whole object where it's supposed to return only a list of items.
I believe it should return $this->items instead of $this.

With the current code, your JView::display() probably assigns a reference to the whole object:

```
$items = $this->get('Items'); // (object) AkceHnedModelActions
$this->assignRef('items', $items);
```

and in your default.php template you iterate over public properties of the object instead of elements of the list array.

```
foreach ($this->items as $i => $item)
```

It's worth checking whether the $i key is 'items'... that would just confirm my theory...

EDIT: A fragment of JModelItem class:

```
/**
 * Method to get an array of data items.
 *
 * @return  mixed  An array of data items on success, false on failure.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function getItems()
{
```